# How to choose from Observable or regular value

Tags: angular, design-patterns, rxjs, observable, ngrx

I've been confusing with `Observable` since getting started with `Angular` (not AngularJS) and `rxjs`.

`Observable` is convenient and provided a FP way of organizing information. However it becomes very cumbersome when mixed with regular values.

For example, suppose we have a data table, in which each row has a checkbox and there is a "select all" checkbox in the header row. A very common use case.

The data source of the data table is an `Observable`. So the pseudo-code will be like:

```
// sample.component.ts, suppose data source comes from ngrx store
rows$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectRows)); 
// sample.component.html
<table [dataSource]="rows$">
```

With this setup, we can implement the check box for each data row as follow, storing the on/off status in local state:

```
// sample.component.ts
state = { selection: {} };
handleSelect(id, event) {
    this.state.selection[id] = event.checked;
}
```

Now here are the problems:

1. In order to calculate the "all selected or not" state, I need to know both `rows$` and `this.state.selection` so that I can tell whether all rows are selected or not.
   However `rows$` is an `Observable` while `this.state.seletion` is a regular object. My options are:

   a) Convert `this.state.selection` into an `Observable` by creating an `rxjs.Subject` and update its value in each `handleSelect()` event handler, then merge this new `Observable` with `rows$` to compute the "all selected" state

   b) Subscribe `rows$` and convert it to a regular array `rows`, then compute the `all selected` state in `handleSelect()`
2. When user clicks the "select all" checkbox, I need to update `this.state.selection` to assign all ids to `true` or `false`. Again all the ids have to be retrieved from `rows$`, which is an `Observable`. So there are two options as well:

   a) Convert "select all" event to an `Observable`, then merge it with `rows$` and update `this.state.selection` as a side effect

   b) The same as 1.b), subscribe `rows$` to `rows` and do the calculation in `handleSelectAll()` handler

For me it looks like the easiest way is to first convert `rows$` to `rows` and DON'T use `Observable` at all in the component. Because in order to use `Observable` I need to convert everything else (state, events, ...) into `Observable`.

But if I am correct, why `ngrx` provides `Observable` interface only?

So I believe I'm thinking soemthing wrong.

I appreciate if anyone could share some light on this.

Comment: If you're using NGRX, typically you would dispatch an action that updates your value, not amend the value directly, as the values are supposed to be immutable

Comment: @user184994 I totally agree with that point. But the point here is that we don't put everything into a global store. As the datatable select state in above example, it's completely local and no need to be managed by ngrx.

Comment: @user184994 and I kind of understand your point that, by using ngrx every state can be an `Observable`. Yes that's reasonable, I just wonder whether "everything is an Observable" is the correct way of using angular.

Comment: Is the correct way of using NGRX, but you dont *have* to use angular that way. As you say, you can subscribe to the observable, and just use the value that's emitted instead.

Comment: But also, not **all** state needs to the live in the NGRX state store-- only shared state. It's perfectly valid to keep some state within the component if that's the only place it's used. Only you know you're application well enough to decide that though.

Comment: @user184994 Thank you. will keep that in mind. (Well if we use snapshot in the component I would rather ngrx just gives snapshot instead of observables)

Comment: Why would you use an Observable as an input though? I would simple use an async pipe so you can compare two regular values.

Comment: Thank you @ChristianS. . Although I don't know how to use async pipe in component but you inspired me to use `this.rows$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(..)` to do the job. This is a more convenient way to convert observable to value. Thank you!

Comment: @charlee I added an answer to show what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to elaborate a bit on my idea:

```
<table [dataSource]="rows$ | async">
```

If you do not want to to do this you can subscribe to your observable in your component (before passing it into the *dataSource* @Input).

Be aware that subscribing to an observable leads to a subscription which you should unsubscribe from in OnDestroy lifecycle hook.

```
subscription: any;
ngOnInit() {
 this.subscription = this.rows$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((result) => {
 this.rows = result;
 }); 
}

ngOnDestroy() {
this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

You can find more info here: https://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/ I would probably go for the async pipe since it is the easiest way.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like everyone is saying "don't use Observable too much" :)

Comment: The key question is do you have a stream of data that is constantly updated? Otherwise you do not really need the Observable.